# How to get a date from a timeZone (Moment Timezone)?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Even if the [Moment Timezone documentation](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) is pretty good, I'm facing a problem. How to simply get a timezone date ?

On an IOS app, i need to get the date from a timeZone, but not related on the system where my app is running.

Basically if my app was used in USA, I would like be able to get, in real time, "Europe/Paris" date in a moment().

Is this possible using Moment Timezone ?

```js
// This line is giving me the smartphone's system date
var today = moment().tz('Europe/Paris');
console.log(today.format());

// This line is giving me the smartphone's system date less one hour
var today2 = moment().tz('Etc/GMT-1');
console.log(today2.format());

// I have no clue where this date is coming from, it doesn't related to my system hour
var today3 = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(today3.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The results you have all look correct. The times you're getting are the current times in those time zones.

Comment: Yeah, i know this should be correct, but when i'm changing manually my smartphone's hour, it's changing also these results using Moment().tz()...

Comment: What do you mean 'changing manually my smartphone's hour'? If you set the time to a wrong value, your phone, and therefore your code, won't know the correct time.

Comment: Exemple : it's presently 6:49 pm in France. So i would like my `var today = moment().tz('Europe/Paris');` gives me : `Sun Jul 01 2018 06:49:00 GMT+0200`. To verify if this, is giving me the right answer, i'm modifying my smartphone's clock and testing my app. Because i don't want a result related to the smartphone's system clock. Am i more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let today = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles")
```

This should get the current date with the call to moment() and change the timezone it with tz. [See docs here.](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/)

For debugging, try it this way: moment.tz accepts both a date, and a tz to change the date to.

```
let now = moment()
console.log(now)
let nowTZ = moment.tz(now, "America/Los_Angeles");
console.log(nowTZ)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i've tried, but it's not working...When i'm changing manually my smartphone's hour, it's changing also these results using Moment().tz().

Comment: I added a different way to do it that should help debug this - what are the outputs of the two console.log statements in my updated answer?

Comment: Arf, i guess it's not possible to get a date from a different timezone without refering to the system clock where `Moment Timezone` is used. From the first `console.log()` I'm getting my smartphone's clock time. And in the second one, it's the Los Angeles time calculated from my smarpthone's clock time.